# ADB over USB Device Offline - LG Nexus 4 + Kubuntu 13

Tags: android, debugging, adb, ubuntu, nexus-4

LG Nexus 4

Android 4.3 (USB DEBUGGING ACTIVE)

ADB 1.0.31
 on Kubuntu 13

My /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules is taken from here https://code.google.com/p/51-android/

Like i said everything i got with #adb devices command is:

```
List of devices attached 
00b453e41******        offline
```

(i censored the id)

Any other info that could be userful?

Comment: `adb kill-server`, then `adb devices`..Tried?

Comment: Yess, already tried :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i solved by myself, it seems it was an issue of permissions.
Just made my user:group owner of the /home/user/.android folder (and all files inside), the owner was root before and i think this was the problem. Now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for people that might find themselves looking for one:

For Android 4.3

Under Developer options, click "Revoke USB debugging authorizations:

(I have no idea if in case of multiple authorized computers the additional keys are in a new line of the file or if they are in new files. I have only 1 computer.)

stop all adb processes "killall adb" in linuxoids and "taskkill /IM adb.exe" in windows or simply the taskmanager in both.

restart the phone

toggle usb debugging off and on

connect

use adb

click authorize

works